# Bootstrap4 button collapse and Parallax-js not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, parallax.js

Bootstrap collaspe div is not pushing the parallax div, but instead going on top of it.
See here: https://codepen.io/carlo-designer/pen/zYZoNYM
Code is below:

```html
<div class="container my-5">


<!-- Collapse -->  
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
  </div>
</div>
  
  
<!-- Parallax.js --> 
<div class="parallax-window" style="height:300px;" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://source.unsplash.com/4YhwiEsL0AQ/1000x600"></div>  
</div>  



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax.js/1.5.0/parallax.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea where it may come from ?
Thanks

Comment: The Bootstrap collapse div isn’t pushing your parallax div down because your parallax div isn’t *there* (below the collapsing div). Parallax.js creates a fixed-position element for the image at the start of the document body and then positions the image on the page using transform. The only time the image *moves* is when there is a page resize event.